# Can I have a cloudwatch alarm when a custom metric isn't being produced?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm running a python process on an EC2 instance, and I want to alarm if it stops working properly.  My plan was to have it add a custom metric data point every minute, and have a custom alarm if no data points are set for 5 minutes, say.

Is this possible?  Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, if you use `SampleCount` for the statistic, not `Average` or `Sum`. Then you can trigger an alert if the number of samples is less than a certain threshold.

(On a side note: `Average` or `Sum` would eventually go into `Insufficient Data` status rather than `Alarm`, if no samples are received at all.)

Comment: Therefore, set your CloudWatch Alarm to send a notification when it enters the `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state (not just when in ALARM state).

Comment: @JohnR That was a bit too obvious, wasn't it? :)  Of course you can do that, but sometimes you really just want to count samples, and in that case any average/sum statistics may not make sense at all, hence my explanation. In this particular case, both works, I agree :)